# how to create city state country dropdown UIComponent in magento 2 admin form

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent, forms

how to create city state country dropdown UIComponent in Magento 2 admin form,
like when we select one country then state of that country is shown.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> app/code/Ktpl/Timeslot/view/adminhtml/ui_component/ktpl_timeslot_timeslot_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">ktpl_timeslot_timeslot_form.timeslot_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">General Information</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button class="Ktpl\Timeslot\Block\Adminhtml\Timeslot\Edit\BackButton" name="back"/>
            <button class="Ktpl\Timeslot\Block\Adminhtml\Timeslot\Edit\DeleteButton" name="delete"/>
            <button class="Ktpl\Timeslot\Block\Adminhtml\Timeslot\Edit\SaveButton" name="save"/>
            <button class="Ktpl\Timeslot\Block\Adminhtml\Timeslot\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton" name="save_and_continue"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>ktpl_timeslot_timeslot_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>ktpl_timeslot_timeslot_form.timeslot_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="timeslot_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="*/*/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Ktpl\Timeslot\Model\Timeslot\DataProvider" name="timeslot_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>timeslot_id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>timeslot_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general">
        <settings>
            <label/>
        </settings>
        <field name="country_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Timeslot</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="region">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Region</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Timeslot</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">15</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="state_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Region</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Timeslot</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">region</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id</item>
                        <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field formElement="input" name="city_id" sortOrder="30">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Timeslot</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">City</label>
                <dataScope>city_id</dataScope>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: hello thanks for your reply but city is not working

Comment: Mean you want to filter the city filed as well. When we select the state at that time it filters the city and adds to the city dropdown.

Comment: yes sir absolutely i want to do same

Comment: In the current code, I have only updated the state filed only.i will try to update the city filed and update you. if i can do this as well

Comment: thanks for your great help I will love to hear from you!!

Comment: @Kushal: how to achieve the same in case if we have multiple country and region dropdowns.

Comment: @NarendraVyas Have you added city drop down in admin customer address ?